# NSXMLParser : where store values?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I want to that my app will work with `XML` file as some kind of pre - initializer. I want to analyse xml file and then draw screens. So for example i have a xml file in struct:

```
<app>
   <screens>        
    <screen name="myscreen1">
            <font fontsize="32" fontcolor="#000000" fontface="font.ttf"/>

            <button tmpl="bk"/>

            <list area="0px 74px 100% 100%">
                <item tmpl="myitem1" target="myitemelsewhere">
                    <image tmpl="myitem1" img="myimg1.png"/>
                    <text tmpl="myitem1">Test</text>
                </item>
                <item tmpl="myitem2" target="myitemelsewhere">
                    <image tmpl="myitem2" img="myimg2.png"/>
                    <text tmpl="myitem2">Test</text>
                </item>
             </list>
    </screen>
<!--screen 2 the same way -->
</screens>
</app>
```

I implement `NSXMLparser` and i can simply read attributes and tags. That's **not** an issue. My question is. When I get the first element (ex myscreen1) what is the best idea where to put it, and grab all the screen declaration tags and attributes later? `NSSet`? `NSDictionary`? `NSArray`? For example:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    element = [NSMutableString string];

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"screen"])
    {
        //What should i do here to tell my app to store all attributes? Where to put this?
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a sneak peak of XML. In actual xml is many, many more parameters, and i don't want variables for every one of them. I'd like to think there is a way that i create a Dictionary/Array/Set (maybe array of dictionaries), and then, when i think of add some new parameters it will be extremly simple.

Comment: I think you're on to something there. Try reading the XML docs and/or looking at some sample code, then try some things and get back to us. Research effort

Comment: Why XML docs have something to do with it? I have a XML file ready to parse. I can't change it the way i want. I do my reseach and asking what is the best way to store my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually have a variable to keep the data which is streaming in and a variable to store the XML tag you are processing. The place that you give above is for setting the XML tag that you're currently processing. Here's a great piece of example code to get you started:

http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48

Comment: Great example. So I can create variables to a class, and this is still might be in progress. Thx, that exmplain a lot.

Comment: Yeah, create a class for whatever you are storing from the XML, and the class has some variables. Maybe a User class with userName and userPhoto variables.

Comment: dead link :-(   actually what I'm hoping to find is sample code to read an XML into a hierarchy of dictionaries. Any sample code? Seems like this sort of thing should be written by Apple.